# angularjs - how to trigger directive on hide element

Tags: angularjs

I have a hide element with custom directive

```
<div style="display:none" my-directive></div>
```

And a `$watch` is added in `my-directive`
My question is how to trigger this directive even if the element is `display:none`or `visibility: hidden` when the watched data changed.

Comment: So you want your containing (parent) element to be displayed if the data is changed in `my-directive`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a $scope.$watch in the controller of your directive and it does not have a private scope on selected variable then change in parent scope will be noticed by the directive even if its DOM element is hidden.

```
//in directive
$scope.$watch('myparentvar', function(neVal, oldVal){

})
```

Answer (score 0):

other way is to use `two way binding` or `=` in directive.

I have used a `variable` named `target` 
here's a [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YgAerXX3t0528EiP62D9?p=preview)